# How long should I wait after a staffing promise is made before sending follow up?

Tags: management, negotiation, politics

Fifteen months ago I wrote to my supervisor asking for a promotion that included requests for:

1. A title change
2. A 15% salary adjustment
3. Paid PMP training
4. A new staff member to absorb my existing duties

All was agreed to, and all was provided as promised except the new staff member.  Over the past months several discussions were had, and several plans were made, but so far no action has been taken.  Has an appropriate amount of time elapsed to write a formal follow-up request, asking for the details of the staffing plan?  I hesitate, because they did give me everything else I asked for, but I also feel that my career has stagnated without the ability to offload my existing duties.

Comment: We talk on a regular basis. I only send letters when it pertains to my employment and I want an "official" company response.  I have mentioned it to my supervisor a few times; he has told me he wants to move forward but he is getting pushback from executive management.  I thought a letter would give him ammunition that new staff is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that sufficient time has gone by that you can submit a formal request. We're talking over a year since the initial request.

I would make sure to include a few things:

1. Specifics (again) of why you need the new staff member.
2. The specific qualifications of the new staffer.
3. **Describe what new and wonderful things you can do when you get him/her** and try to do a cost/benefit analysis if you can.
4. Describe the harm that's being done by not having him/her.

Basically, make sure you put it in terms that make business sense. It's usually all about the money. You have to remember though, you're currently doing all this stuff and it's not costing them an extra person.

The reality is though that you may end up having to move on.  It's an unfortunate reality that many businesses don't treat insiders any differently once they've been promoted.  They're still (in their eyes) the person they hired years ago.

But as I said, I think the key is to justify it in monetary terms **not personal terms**. Your career stagnation is really not their concern.

Comment: Last sentence is reality

Answer (score 2):

Plans change.

A new staff member likely costs many times the rest of your package (title change, salary adjustment, training).  It is entirely possible that management had to wait until the next fiscal year and at that time could no longer justify it.

You should probably treat this as a separate / new request.  Show how adding a staff member would benefit the business and be cost effective. Be prepared to spend months making your case, and document as many facts (not opinions, feelings, or conclusions) as you can.